# GIT global config for ignore end-of-line white spaces

Tags: git, whitespace, end-of-line

Even though I have not changed anything in one of file, I am getting one file in modified files list using `> git status`.

When I saw that file using `> git diff`, it is displaying all lines are removed and all lines (*same*) are added, but when I use `> git diff --ignore-space-change`, git is not displaying any change.

I am sure it something related to `end of line`, but strange is I am not getting this behavior with all the files..! And also, all of developers are using the Windows.

Now, I want to tell git in some way so that it will not consider `end of line white spaces`  into consideration while I do `git pull` or `git diff`.

**My Git Attributes**

```
# Auto detect text files and perform LF normalization
* text=auto
```

**My Git Configs**

```
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
pack.packsizelimit=2g
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
sendemail.smtpserver=/bin/msmtp.exe
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
user.name=XXX
user.email=XXX@gmail.com
core.autocrlf=true
core.crlf=true
colors.ui=true
auto.crlf=true
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
core.hidedotfiles=dotGitOnly
core.crlf=true
```

Please help me.

Comment: Start by making sure that `core.autocrlf` is set to false, and see if the issue persists after a fresh new clone.

Comment: It was set to false first and I have got some suggestions from web and tried with `true` last. :(

Comment: Then try to remove the .gitattribute text auto directive, clone again and see if the issue persists

Comment: Thanks @VonC for your time and suggestions, I have tried to change those settings and final result is random..! I have cloned the repo twice with same configs and first time it's was showing files with difference and second time it was fine..! :(

Comment: Strange indeed. This should not be random.

Comment: Have you managed to resolve this issue?

Comment: I have still not resolved this issue, we are creating bad GIT history as of now.